# Probability tree question - conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I have a question which is for some reason is not making sense in the results I get -

90% of candidates to be a president are not fit. There are three interviews to become a president. In each interview there is 70% to be rejected if you're not a fit and 60% to be accepted if you're a fit. all the interviews are not depended and the final decision is made by the majority. 
What is probability that someone is a fit  if it was decided to reject him?

So I know it's a probability with a condition: (to be fit| to be rejected). 
I did a tree of probabilities and tried to put it in the formula - P(to be fit and to be rejected) / P(to be rejected).

So my three was starting at to be fit (0.1) and not to fit (0.9).
Each branch was to be accepted if you're a fit (0.6), to be rejected if you're a fit (0.4),
to be rejected if you're not a fit (0.7) and to be accepted if you're not a fit (0.3).

Since it's not depended I multiplied the results of the three interviews. I understood that since it's decided by the majority, you need to be rejected twice or all three times.

The tree is getting messy, am I missing something and the solution is simplier?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The majority thing can be dealt with separately from the conditional probability calculation: The probability that an unfit candidate is rejected by a majority is $\binom32\cdot0.7^2\cdot0.3+\binom33\cdot0.7^3=0.784$, and the probability that a fit candidate is accepted by a majority is $\binom32\cdot0.6^2\cdot0.4+\binom33\cdot0.6^3=0.648$.

Now we can calculate the conditional probability unencumbered by voting procedures:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathsf P(\text{fit}\mid\text{rejected})
&=&
\frac{\mathsf P(\text{rejected}\mid\text{fit})\mathsf P(\text{fit})}{\mathsf P(\text{rejected})}
\\
&=&
\frac{\mathsf P(\text{rejected}\mid\text{fit})\mathsf P(\text{fit})}{\mathsf P(\text{rejected}\mid\text{fit})\mathsf P(\text{fit})+\mathsf P(\text{rejected}\mid\text{unfit})\mathsf P(\text{unfit})}
\\
&=&
\frac{(1-0.648)(1-0.9)}{(1-0.648)(1-0.9)+0.784\cdot0.9}
\\
&=&
\frac{22}{463}
\\
&\approx&
4.75\%\;.
\end{eqnarray}