# Constructing a probability tree from a series of conditional events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, decision-trees

In a game, there are a series of attacks, each with a known probability of success.

As a specific example, let's say that there are two potential attacks that can be made against a single defender. Each has a probability of 0.59 to succeed. If the first attack succeeds, the defender is destroyed, and therefore no subsequent attack can be performed.

[Here is a tree](https://mermaid.live/edit#eyJjb2RlIjoiZmxvd2NoYXJ0IExSXG4gICAgcDFbQXR0YWNrIDFdLS0-fHdpbjogMC41OXxwMV93aW5bV2luPGJyPjAuNTldXG4gICAgcDEtLT58bG9zZTogMC40MXxwMltBdHRhY2sgMl1cbiAgICBwMi0tPnx3aW46IDAuNTl8cDJfd2luW1wiV2luPGJyPjAuNDEgKiAwLjU5ID0gMC4yNFwiXVxuICAgIHAyLS0-fGxvc2U6IDAuNDF8cDJfbG9zZVtcIkxvc2U8YnI-MC40McKyID0gMC4xN1wiXSIsIm1lcm1haWQiOiJ7XG4gIFwidGhlbWVcIjogXCJkZWZhdWx0XCJcbn0iLCJ1cGRhdGVFZGl0b3IiOmZhbHNlLCJhdXRvU3luYyI6dHJ1ZSwidXBkYXRlRGlhZ3JhbSI6ZmFsc2V9) of how I think this can be modeled:

[image: Probability tree, hopefully correctly modeling a sequence of encounters]

Based on the above tree, I think the following statements are correct:

1. There is a $P(0.59)$ probability of winning in the first attack
2. There is a $P(0.83)$ probability of destroying the defender (we don't care if it takes 1 or 2 attacks, just that it is destroyed in one of them). This can be calculated in two ways:

   1. $1 - (0.42^2) = 0.83$ (the probability that the bottom branch does not occur)
   2. $0.59 + 0.24 = 0.83$ (the probability that one of the two Win leaves is reached)
3. There is a $0.41 * 0.59 = 0.24$ probability of losing the first attack, but winning the second
4. It is not a coincidence that the leaf probabilities all add up to $1$; this simply indicates that we've fully captured the probability space

My questions are:

1. Are the above statements correct?
2. Is there an alternative way of deriving this? That is, for a given branch of the above tree, it seems that it could be represented instead as some variation of $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A|B) \ P(B)}{P(A)}$, as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3643802/1010552), but I have no idea how to get there

Comment: (1) Yes, this is all correct; (2) I doubt there are (fundamentally) other ways of *deriving* "this", but there may be other ways of *writing* /expressing "this". However, you would need to be more specific what "*this*" means: one, or all four of your statements? I am also thinking that other approaches towards writing down this may be more obscure - the probability tree is a very nice way to express what's going on, "one picture is worth thousand words" etc. etc. - no need to muddle things up with math symbolism if you don't need to.

Comment: Thank you. I think for (2) I meant something like "for a given leaf of the tree, how might I derive the probability without first constructing the tree". But after writing this out, I think it's trivial: since I know the probabilities, simply multiply them all together.

Comment: Well, you are sort-of using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability) : let $A$ be the event of Win in Attack1, and $B$ the event of Win in Attack2, you want e.g. $P(A^c\cap B)=P(B\mid A^c)P(A^c)=P(B)P(A^c)=0.59\times 0.41$ because $P(B\mid A^c)=P(B)$, because $B$ and $A$ (thus $B$ and $A^c$) are independent. ($A^c$ is the complement of $A$.) Can be written that way, but I still prefer to see the tree!